# How to write Elixir macro similar to Ecto's field/2?

Tags: macros, elixir, abstract-syntax-tree, ecto

I'm learning Elixir and came across such situation:
I have an Ecto schema and I want to make a function like "get_by" that takes a column name and it's value as an arguments like this: `get_by(:id, 7)` 
So the working version of the function would be like this:

```
def get_by(column, value) do
  Repo.all(
    from(
      r in __MODULE__,
      where: field(r, ^column) == ^value,
    )
  )
end
```

**I know this is fully functional but I was wondering how the `field` macro works.**
The original code is too hard to read for me. I was trying to play with AST in macro, but nothing seems to work. The best I had was this:

```
defmacro magic(var, {:^, _, [{column, _, _}]}) do
  dot = {:., [], [var, column]}
  {dot, [], []}
end
```

But this returns `r.column` instead of the atom bound to `column` variable.
How the macro should be written to return `r.id`?

Comment: If you look at the source code for `Ecto.Query.API.field/2`, it's just a placeholder: https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v3.2.5/lib/ecto/query/api.ex#L353 The query macro looks for calls to it and treats them as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the source code for [`Ecto.Query.API.field/2`](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/0ccb924ac52caebd6936de92302239e08889d116/lib/ecto/query/api.ex#L353), you’ll see that the explicit call to this function (it’s not a macro btw) *raises*.

That is because it makes sense only inside [`Ecto.Query.from/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html?#from/2) macro.

What you want is still possible to some extent; not with a dot notation (AFAICT, but with an `Access`)

```rb
defmodule M do
  defmacro magic(a1, {:^, _, [a2]}) do
    quote do: unquote(a1)[unquote(a2)]
  end
end
import M
{r, column} = {%{id: 42}, :id}
magic(r, ^column)
#⇒ 42
```

I was unable to get `quote do: unquote(a1).unquote(a2)` work without absolutely nasty tricks like inplace eval.

To better understand macros, you probably should clarify for yourself what AST is available where.

---

I highly recommend [Metaprogramming Elixir](https://pragprog.com/book/cmelixir/metaprogramming-elixir) by Chris McCord.

Comment: Actually what I am looking for is the way to do exactly what `field` does, so to insert into where clause a condition "where r.id = 7" while `id` is stored as atom in some variable. Of course outside `from` it wouldn't make sense to use it.

Comment: `field` does not do anything, it is handled as a plain atom in the AST by `from/2` as I said.

Comment: Ok I think I understand now. So basically the `from/2` is looking for `:field` and handling it, right?

Comment: Yes, same for `fragment/2`. `Ecto.Query.API.field/2`is just there so they can attach documentation to it